# Command Line Arguments With "-" Prefix

Tags: c++, command-line, arguments

I'm trying to write a program which I'll be able to start with custom arguments. Like in this example "program.exe -width 1920 -height 1080". I wrote a simple code, which should work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (argv[i] == "-width")
        {
            std::cout << "Width: " << argv[++i] << "\n";
        }
        else if (argv[i] == "-height")
        {
            std::cout << "Height: " << argv[++i] << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this program doesn't work. It's not displaying anything. I also tried checking this code line by line with debugger, but when `argv[i] == "-width"` it just skips it.

Is there a way to fix it or there are just some other methods of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing pointers, not strings. To compare strings via `==`, you should use `std::string`.

Also you should check if the elements `argv[++i]` exists.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (argv[i] == std::string("-width") && i + 1 < argc)
        {
            std::cout << "Width: " << argv[++i] << "\n";
        }
        else if (argv[i] == std::string("-height") && i + 1 < argc)
        {
            std::cout << "Height: " << argv[++i] << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the s suffix

```
cout << ("wilson" == "wilson"s) << endl;
```

output:

```
1
```

Comment: I don't know why, but when I'm adding 's' letter behind the string, it shows me an error. 
E2486 Unable to find user-defined literal operator

Comment: @MiłoszBrzechczyn `E` errors (assuming visual studio) can usually be ignored. Try compiling, and see if its still an error. If it is, make sure to `#include <string>`, and `using namespace std::string_literals;`

Comment: Yup, I added `using namespace` and it works. I didn't know before about any s suffix, but thank you.